# control looses value set in javascript function on server side event

Tags: asp.net

In javascript function I checking checkbox and setting value to label after satisfication of perticular condition.But in serverside event I am getting checkbox1.checked = false and text of label is default text of that label, not modified one.Why this is happening?How to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

chek if you set AutoPostBack to true

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```